# SQL Search ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am building a mock car rental site. I have to check to see if a certain car is reserved or not. I have a table in my SQL database for each car. Each car's table contains a datetime column. Each day a car is reserved an entry is made in said table. Given the users request I know which table to search. My problem is writing a sqlcommand that searches the columns for a specific date time. If it finds nothing then good let us make a reservation, otherwise I cannot make the reservation.
to add something to a table this works for me:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO reservationTable (resNumber,pickUp, dropOff) Values(@resNumber,@pickUp,@dropOff)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@resNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pickUp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = reservation.pickUp;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dropOff", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = reservation.ret;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Anyone suggest a search command like this for my intents and purposes? Say for example I wanted to search reservationTable for a specific resNumber.

Comment: Well, first I would probably recommend not creating a table for every car.  What happens when you get a new car for the service?  What happens when one is sold?  Also, would be helpful if you provided some data structures, and possibly some sample data.

Comment: @YoungGuy why not have one table like a log. Then select on where dropOff > GETDATE() and CarID = xxx

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @BertEvans.  I think you're having issues due to a poor database schema design.  Also, more code samples will definitely help.

Comment: Well I am not too sure on how to design the table most efficiently. I can add or create sample data as I choose, I just have to have 4 classes of vehicle..Compact,Standard, SUV, and MiniVan. All cars are available to start.

Comment: Fully agree. One table per car? You just told everyone on the planet you better work atmcdonalds serve bburgers- this is database rape. Get a book about how sql databases work.

Comment: Your design assumes that the user knows what car they want.  Sometimes people don't care and ask for a list of what's available and pick the cheapest, most comfortable etc.  under that guise, you'd have to search every table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your where clause will be something like

```
WHERE Dropoff >= @requestedPickup and Pickup <= @requestedDropoff
```

This seems strange but test it; should identify any existing records which overlap the requested reservation; thus negating the requested reservation. if no records are returned, then the requested reservation would be valid.

Comment: I agree with some of the above comments however, a separate table for each car doesn't scale well;

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "Select resNumber,pickUp, dropOff 
     from reservationtable 
     where resnumber=@resNumber"), con); 

cmd.Parameters.Add("@resNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i; 
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{ 
    while (dr.read())
    {
     // do stuff with results.
    }
}
```